# c# Connect to Oracle database

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, entity-framework

I have a c# application with Entity Framework with a connection to an Oracle Database. This connections works fine on my development pc and also on an older shared windows 2008 server.

Now I deployed it on a new windows 2012 test server and the server throws an error that he can't connect to the database.

The server is available when I telnet its IP and port 1521, so it should be connectable.

This is the relevant web.config code:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Context" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXX)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)));USER ID=XXX;PASSWORD=XXX;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=False" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
</connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>  

<DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
    <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

This is the error I got:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException
>
> "An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the
>   connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is
>   correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used
>   to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on
>   DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the
>   failure."
>
> "Connection request timed out"

---

**Question:** How can I solve this database connection? Do I miss something?

Comment: Can you connect with other tools, e.g. SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having struggled some years ago with connection to Oracle servers I used the [TOAD freeware version](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle) to debug the connection strings. It was a life saver. Also, I needed the assistance of the Oracle DBAs.

It looks like your application might not be able to find the server.

Comment: The problem was solved by opening some other ports by the network administrator. Port 1521 was already open, but the connection to the database uses more different ports.

Comment: @RPelzer what other ports?

Comment: That would be a question for your DBA